# I get weird extra letters behind my output in my terminal. Any clue why?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, cs50

When I run my code (it is a code that replaces vowels (except `u`) with digits, it works but there is a bug where there are 2 extra characters at the end of the word if the word is beyond 9 or 10 letters (I think). It is never the same letters but it is sometimes a weird question mark diamond thing. I have heard somewhere I had to do something with a null at the end of my string, not sure how to do that or if it would even work.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Give me a word: " );
    int j = strlen(word);
    int i;
    char new[j + 1];

    new[0] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'e')
        {
            new[i] = '3';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'i')
        {
            new[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            new[i] = '6';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'o')
        {
            new[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            new[i] = word[i], 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", new);
}
```

Here are 3 random outputs I get when putting in the word `coordination`:

```
c00rd1n6t10n�U
c00rd1n6t10nEV
c00rd1n6t10nQV
```

Comment: Try putting the `'\0'` on the **end** of the array, not the **start**... (And, what's the meaning of `, 0;` in the last `else` block? It's not invalid, but it's not useful, either.)

Comment: `word[i], 0` does not copy two letters.  Just assign one letter at a time.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Honestly didnt notice that last , 0 when posting. That was me trying some things out. If i move the \0 to the end of the array my output becomes blank.

Comment: You could just loop from 0 to j + 1. That will copy the null terminator too (assuming you get rid of the bogus `, 0` from the last `else` block).

Comment: I will also suggest to not use Variable length array (for new), rather use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` or `calloc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less your original code, but the `new` array is initialized with `'a'`s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* word = "coordination";
  int j = strlen(word);
  int i;
  char new[50] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

  for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
  {
    if (word[i] == 'e')
    {
      new[i] = '3';
    }
    else if (word[i] == 'i')
    {
      new[i] = '1';
    }
    else if (word[i] == 'a')
    {
      new[i] = '6';
    }
    else if (word[i] == 'o')
    {
      new[i] = '0';
    }
    else
    {
      new[i] = word[i];
    }
  }

//  new[j] = 0;   // uncomment this

  printf("%s\n", new);
}
```

You simply don't put a null terminator, hence you get this output:

```
c00rd1n6t10naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

The `aaa...` at the end are leftovers from the array initialisation of `new`.

Uncomment `//  new[j] = 0;`  and you'll see that the output is as expected:

```
c00rd1n6t10n
```

In your code you get unpredictable output because the `new` array has not been initialized and you don't put a null terminator.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly and i have learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the new version of your code:

- you initialize `new[0] = 0;` which is harmless but useless if the original string pointed to by `word` is not empty.
- the statement `new[i] = word[i], 0;` is not invalid, but the `, 0` part is useless and does nothing.  The statement is comma expression: the assignment `new[i] = word[i]` followed by a constant expression `0` which has no effect.
- you do not set the null terminator after all bytes stored into `new`, so the last byte of the array remains uninitialized and `printf` outputs it and the following ones until it finds a null byte (one with a zero value).  This is a good example of undefined behavior: anything can happen, including your program exiting with a segmentation fault.  You should set the null terminator with `new[i] = '\0';` after the end of the loop, as can be seen in my answer to your previous question.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string word = get_string("Give me a word: ");
    int j = strlen(word);
    int i;
    char new[j + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'e')
        {
            new[i] = '3';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'i')
        {
            new[i] = '1';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            new[i] = '6';
        }
        else if (word[i] == 'o')
        {
            new[i] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            new[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    new[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", new);
    return 0;
}
```